# Regex negative lookahead ignoring comments

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm having problems with this regex. I want to pull out just `MATCH3`, because the others, `MATCH1` and `MATCH2` are commented out.

```
#   url(r'^MATCH1/$',),
   #url(r'^MATCH2$',),
    url(r'^MATCH3$',), # comment
```

The regex I have captures all of the MATCH's.

```
(?<=url\(r'\^)(.*?)(?=\$',)
```

How do I ignore lines beginning with a comment? With a negative lookahead? Note the `#` character is not necessarily at the start of the line.

EDIT: sorry, all answers are good! the example forgot a comma after the `$'` at the end of the match group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need to use lookarounds here, you could look for possible leading whitespace and then match "url" and the preceding context; capturing the part you want to retain.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """#   url(r'^MATCH1/$',),
   #url(r'^MATCH2$',),
    url(r'^MATCH3$',), # comment"""
>>> re.findall(r"(?m)^\s*url\(r'\^([^$]+)", s)
['MATCH3']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^\s*#.*$|(?<=url\(r'\^)(.*?)(?=\$'\))
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rK5lU1/37

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^\s*#.*$|(?<=url\(r\'\^)(.*?)(?=\$\'\))', re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
test_str = "# url(r'^MATCH1/$'),\n #url(r'^MATCH2$'),\n url(r'^MATCH3$') # comment"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is the only place where you need to match, then match beginning of line followed by optional whitespace followed by `url`:

```
(?m)^\s*url\(r'(.*?)'\)
```

If you need to cover more complicated cases, I'd suggest using `ast.parse` instead, as it truly understands the Python source code parsing rules.

```
import ast

tree = ast.parse("""(
#   url(r'^MATCH1/$'),
   #url(r'^MATCH2$'),
    url(r'^MATCH3$') # comment
)""")

class UrlCallVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_Call(self, node):
        if getattr(node.func, 'id', None) == 'url':
            if node.args and isinstance(node.args[0], ast.Str):
                print(node.args[0].s.strip('$^'))

        self.generic_visit(node)

UrlCallVisitor().visit(tree)
```

prints each first string literal argument given to function named `url`; in this case, it prints `MATCH3`. Notice that the source for `ast.parse` needs to be a well-formed Python source code (thus the parenthesis, otherwise a `SyntaxError` is raised).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can split your lines with '#' if the first element has 'url' in (it doesn't start with # ) you can use `re.search` to match the sub-string that you want :

```
>>> [re.search(r"url\(r'\^(.*?)\$'" ,i[0]).group(1) for i in [line.split('#') for line in s.split('\n')] if 'url' in i[0]]
['MATCH3']
```

Also note that you dont need to sue look-around for your pattern you can just use grouping!